# Morphological Analyzer WordFrame Example-Based Training

Tags: java, trie

I'm working on a project regarding a Morphological Analyzer in Tagalog. It uses a revised WordFrame model for Tagalog, using Trie data structure to store rules and an example-based training set in the form of "root word,transformed word." Using Java as the programming language I'm using this paper on the link below to as reference:

http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dlsu.edu.ph%2Fresearch%2Fcenters%2Fadric%2Fnlp%2FDLSUS%26T-Wordframe.pdf&ei=AyULUfblK8aziQejtoGwDQ&usg=AFQjCNFkzzaLubyrgyOYlOBvvLw3r7isYw&sig2=czsPv7Av1sTbO9DxXmBRYQ&bvm=bv.41867550,d.aGc&cad=rja

I'm having trouble in implementing the last step.

**Here's what I've done so far:**

1. Able to segment words in a table from a training set
2. Have a Trie data structure where I can store rules

**What's unclear:**

1. I understand how I need some conditional probability to determine how to generate the correct transformed word from a root word. However, I'm a bit stuck on how to apply the rules learned. Where do I get the probability from a training set?
2. Do I really need a corpus to get the probabilities? Or is the training set enough?
3. How will the "highest alignment probability" apply in this case?
4. When storing rules learned, like "o->u" on internal vowel changes, do I only store "ou" in my Trie? Or should it include the root word from where it came from.

Thank you in advance.